# Docker compose command is failing with conflict

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am bringing up my project dependencies using docker-compose. So far this used to work

```
docker-compose up -d --no-recreate;
```

However today I tried running the project again after couple of weeks and I was greeted with error message

```
Creating my-postgres ... error

ERROR: for my-postgres  Cannot create container for service postgres: b'Conflict. The container name "/my-postgres" is already in use by container "dbd06bb1d99eda6f075ea688df16e8b355e559e1759f084dee8f3cddfc535b0b". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.'

ERROR: for postgres  Cannot create container for service postgres: b'Conflict. The container name "/my-postgres" is already in use by container "dbd06bb1d99eda6f075ea688df16e8b355e559e1759f084dee8f3cddfc535b0b". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

My docker-compose.yml file is

```
postgres:
    container_name: my-postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
```

Docker version is

```
Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89
```

Docker compose version is

```
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b
```

Intended behavior of this call is to:

- make the container if it does not exist
- start the container if it exists
- just chill and do nothing if the container is already started

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Docker Compose normally assigns a container name based on its current project name and the name of the `services:` block.  Specifying `container_name:` explicitly overrides this; but, it means you can’t launch multiple copies of the same Compose file with different project names (from different directories) because the container name you’ve explicitly chosen won’t be used.

You almost never care what the container name is explicitly.  It only really matters if you’re trying to use plain `docker` commands to manipulate Compose-managed containers; it has no impact on inter-service communication.  Just delete the `container_name:` line.

(For similar reasons you can almost always delete `hostname:` and `links:` sections if you have them with no practical impact on your overall system.)

Comment: This does work and intended behavior is achieved. However the question is why did it stop working in the first place?

Comment: The other implication here is that you have a previous version of this running (probably from a differently-named directory).

Answer (score 19):

In my case I moved the project in an other directory.
When I tryed to run `docker-compose up` it failed because of some conflicts.

With command `docker system prune` I resolved them.

Comment: This is quite a radical solution, but it is very effective.

Comment: `docker container prune` is a better option I guess

Comment: keep simple. Perfect!! It works.

Answer (score 4):

It's caused by being in a different directory than when you last ran `docker-compose up`. One option is to change back to the original directory. Or if you've configured it as a `systemd` service you can use `systemctl`.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, it boils down to the following: (use them base on your use cases)

To clear containers:

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
```

To clear images:

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
```

To clear volumes:

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
```

To clear networks:

```
docker network rm $(docker network ls | tail -n+2 | awk '{if($2 !~ /bridge|none|host/){ print $1 }}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Well...the error message seems pretty straightforward to me...

```
The container name "/my-postgres" is already in use by container
```

If you just want to restart where you left, you should use `docker-compose start`.
Otherwise, just clean up your workspace before running it :

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Straightforward message or not, it's not clear under which conditions it occurs. Apparently docker refuses to create a container with the specified name, because there is already a container by that same name. Which suggests that docker-compose failed to notice it for some reason. Race condition?

Answer (score 2):

Remove **--no-recreate** flag from your docker-compose command. And execute the command again.

$`docker-compose up -d`

- **--no-recreate** is using for preventing accedental updates.

If there are existing containers for a service, and the service’s configuration or image was changed after the container’s creation, docker-compose up picks up the changes by stopping and recreating the containers. To prevent Compose from picking up changes, use the **--no-recreate** flag.

official docker docs.[Link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue

```
dcdown --remove-orphans
```

That worked for me.